# ssh to server, run commands and save output of commands on local machine using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh [username]@[ip] "bash -s" <<EOF
if [condition]
  then 
    echo "success"
  else
    echo "failure"
fi
EOF
```

After running these commands, I want to save the result (ie success/failure) in a file on local machine. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to try is the IO redirection:

```
ssh [username]@[ip] "bash -s" > file.txt <<EOF
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Exit status of ssh is the exit status of the remote command so this should work:

```
( ssh [username]@[ip] [command] && echo success || echo failure ) > result.txt
```